# ASP.NET MVC: how to signal compilation error if a view has error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compiler-construction

My view has errors. I see these errors only if I open the view in Visual Studio.

I would like to see the errors on compile time rather than on execute time.

Does exist a way to obtain this behavior?

Comment: Good question actually, I wouldn't mind knowing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update by hand the .csproj file and add a `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>` that will compile the views as you go.

Here's a link I [googled](http://webdevdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/02/aspnet-mvc-rc-compiler-post-build-step.html), you'll find others as well.

**EDIT:** If it's too slow try setting the build only for Release, edit the csproj file doing something like this; see the docs for [AspNetCompiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164291.aspx) for more details.

```
<!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
   Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
   -->
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="Temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)\..\$(ProjectName)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: You might consider creating a separate build, or using Release, and turning it off for Debug builds. See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about C# compile errors and not things like CSS validation errors.

One thing you can do is add a [Web Deployment Project](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en) to your solution.  When it builds, it will run aspnet_compiler.exe on your project which will expose any of these C# compile errors in .aspx files that otherwise wouldn't be indicated until the .aspx file was compiled on the fly at runtime.